# Numpy/Scipy: Singular Matrix Calculating probability of multivariate observation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability

I'm trying to calculate probabilities for observations in matrices where my rows are observations and my columns are features using python. I always get singular matrix errors, even when using random matrices, so I suspect something is wrong with my code:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np


def get_mean(x, axis=0):
  return x.mean(axis=axis)


def get_sigma(x):
  return np.cov(x, rowvar=False)


def get_probabilities(x, mu, sigma):
  return multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=mu, cov=sigma)


x = np.random.rand(10,10)
t = np.random.rand(1, 10)

mu = get_mean(x)
sigma = get_sigma(x)
p = get_probabilities(t, mu, sigma)
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_probabilities
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py", line 512, in pdf
    psd = _PSD(cov, allow_singular=allow_singular)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py", line 159, in __init__
    raise np.linalg.LinAlgError('singular matrix')
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough data to estimate the covariance matrix `sigma`. `x` needs more rows than columns to estimate a well defined covariance matrix.

This for example will let the code run without problems:

```
x = np.random.rand(100, 10)
```

Alternatively, if you simply don't have enough data, you can use [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) (or shrinkage) to better condition the covariance matrix:

```
sigma += np.eye(10) * 1e-3  # problem: how to chose the factor
```

Scikit-learn has the [`ledoit_wolf`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.ledoit_wolf.html) covariance estimator, which automatically determines the amount of regularization based on the available data.

Comment: Thanks, I failed to realize the toy example that I started using (and posted above) is a bad one because of the lack of rows -- my real data has hundreds of thousands of observations, so this isn't the problem. I think I have a fundamental problem with a lack of variance in my real data that needs further investigation.

Comment: @rumdrums in that case shrinkage can help too :)

Comment: "x needs more rows than columns to estimate a well defined covariance matrix." I think this is incorrect -- cov(x) has rank equal to the number of linearly independent columns of x, if I'm not mistaken. In the example shown above, x almost certainly has rank 10 and therefore so does cov(x) and therefore cov(x) is invertible (aside from the unlikely possibility that rand happens to return a rank-deficient matrix). The answer by Flo Martin identifies the problem as a programming error.

Comment: @rumdrums About lack of variance, look for columns which are constant (all the same value) or multiples of other columns, and omit them.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you for your concern. Please note that the covariance matrix has at most rank n - 1, where n is the number of rows ([details here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178587/why-is-the-rank-of-covariance-matrix-at-most-n-1)). That is why you need more rows than columns. As for Flo Martin's answer; it is plainly wrong I'm sorry to say. `t` has nothing to do with the problem and the suggested fix does not solve the error.

Comment: I've done the easy work of 1) removing certainly highly correlated columns from the dataset and 2) removing columns that are entirely (or mostly) constant, but still the problem occurs, which is why I thought I might have a code problem. I will look into regularization for my next step.

Comment: @rumdrums Dimensionality reduction is also something to consider. What data are you working with?

Comment: @rumdrums Look at eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. If you have a lot of very small eigenvalues, it makes the matrix "almost" singular. Instead of trying to invert the matrix, maybe you can work with a singular value decomposition or something like that. Maybe project the point at which you want to compute the probability density into the subspace spanned by the nonzero (or not-almost-zero) eigenvectors and work with that.

Comment: I agree with @RobertDodier's remark about eigenvectors. You may want to project the PDF back into data space if the subspace is not meaningful for you.

Comment: The data I'm working with is logs from application load balancers, so I have lots of records, but as you can imagine, there is great potential for repetition in the data, which is probably the root of my problem -- I also haven't thought hard enough about properly bucketing categorical variables, which has led to lots of one-hot-encoded columns with few observations. Some of what you've posted is above my head, but it gives me a lot of points for paths forward -- so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `t` is an np.array of shape (1,10) while it should be of shape (10,).

If you replace the line of code

```
t = np.random.rand(1, 10)
```

by

```
t = np.random.rand(10)
```

this works.